# Only one plural form for answer count in the "Following" section of user profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, plurals, follow-post

There is only one plural form for answer count in the ["Following" section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=following&filter=questions&sort=added) of user profile:

> [image: only s]

I don't see the expected 3 forms (one/few/many) in translation. Only the following one: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14842

Comment: Does the same happen for views? Like **"1 views"** :D

Comment: @bad_coder nope, that's all fine with [views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMDkS.png). Screenshot taken from SO in Russian.

Comment: Looks like there is also only one string used in english. 1 answerS is definetly having a S too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed.

> "Pluralization"
> is hard to use in haiku
> syllables galore

Comment: It seems that transifex DB not yet updated, I will wait for it.

Comment: I dont think that you will need to update in transifex, since it is now using the string `#numAnswers# answers` instead of `$numAnswers$ answers`, and the previous was already in the db.

Comment: I got it! You just used other (already existed) strings in that context!