# Pluralization issue for bookmark tooltip: "bookmarked by 1 users"

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks, tooltips, plurals

There's pluralization issue for bookmarked question tooltip, e.g.:

> [image: 1 users]

Such notice can be viable from profile [questions tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=questions) or bounties tab.

Worth noting that that string have correctly pluralized [translations](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=bookmarked%20by%20%5C%24) on ruSO:

> [image: 1 user]

> [image: 2 users]

I can't recall a case when there was an issue on English site, but no related issue on localized one.

Comment: See the conversation below https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360772/pluralization-issue-when-only-one-more-comment-is-to-be-shown-show-1-more-comm

Comment: @Ollie I've [a lot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bplurals%5D+user%3A339911+%5Bbug%5D) of pluralization bug reports, only one is downvoted to negative score, and another one tagged as [by-design], so I will continue to post such bugs :) BTW that's my 777th question on MSE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed.

> "Pluralization"
> is hard to use in haiku
> syllables galore

Comment: Could you please also take a look at this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359599/339911